# How can I restore my carpet's pile after too much cleaning product was used?

Tags: cleaning, carpet

I recently moved into my new place and have found that my carpet on my landing is completely flattened.  I was told by a carpet cleaning company that it has been caused by too much cleaning product from a Vax carpet cleaner.  I want to find a way of removing the excess cleaning solution and bring the carpet pile back up to what it should be.  Any ideas on how i could do it without bringing in a cleaning company to do it.

Comment: a rubdown w/ a soaking wet hot towel will absorb anything water-soluble. repeat as needed.

Answer (score 6):

Rent a carpet cleaner and don't put in any detergent. Just use hot water.